Image of region under a projective transformation
Problem goes like this
Given the region ${F} = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0 \leq x \leq 1, y \geq 0 \}$ and the matrix $M$ of the projective transformation $f$ of the extended affine plane, $$ M = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 2 & -1 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}. $$ Determine the image ${F}' = f({F})$ of the region ${F}$ under the transformation $f$.
My idea is to write $F$ in homogenous coordinates and multiply by matrix $M$
$$
{F} = \left\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x \geq 0, y \geq 0 \right\}
$$
$$
= \left\{ \left( x_1:x_2: 1 \right) \mid  x_1 \geq 0, x_2 \geq 0 \right\}
$$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & 2 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
2x_1 - x_3 \\
2x_2 - x_3 \\
2x_2 + x_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
{F}' =  \left\{ (2x_1 - x_3:2x_2 - x_3: 2x_2 + x_3) 
\mid \frac{x_1}{x_3} \geq 0, \frac{x_2}{x_3} \geq 0 \right\}
$$
Does anybody have an idea if I'm taking the right path here?
Also, I don't know how to continue from here, maybe this is the final solution?
